# AngularJS render FontAwesome html code for icons in templates

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking for a way to place icons in all kinds of places using a function in the controller.

My controller has:

```
$scope.fa_icon = function (icon) {
  return "<span class='fa fa-" + icon + "'></span>";
};
```

template.html

```
<button> {{ fa_icon("headphones") }} Music </button>
```

Currently in the template.html I see the HTML code instead of the rendered html code.

If I need to use `ng-bind-html` I will also need some variable in a format of `<p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>` but the result of `fa_icon("headphones")` already contains a `<span>` tags and I don't want to wrap it with another tag just as a patch.

So I was wondering if there's anything I can use inside the controller to tweak this...

Comment: What about a directive for this case? Pass the tag element and class you wish and return the compiled html. Maybe the best, clean solution.

Comment: but calling the directive itself - meaning creating a tag with some stuff in it, no ? can you post an example ? I don't see how it's different than creating some custom tag <fa class='fa fa-icon'></fa>

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ng-attr` like this

```
<button><i ng-attr-class="{{ fa_icon('headphones') }}"></i></button>

$scope.fa_icon = function (icon) {
  return "fa fa-" + icon;
};
```

As this is still "ugly" you should have a look at [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive).

Comment: yeah but the tags are hard-coded, I want to place them in the function itself, because I keep switching between span/i tags until I get something right